# Making symbols bold in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use pch=3 in ggplot2 geom_point and I want to make it bold. I can increase the size but could not make it bold. Any suggestions?

```
 libray(ggplot2)
 z=data.frame(x=1:12,y=c(3,5,1,6,2,9,7,10,11,4,12,8))
 ggplot(z,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point(pch=3,size=5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use `stroke` argument:

```
library(ggplot2)
z=data.frame(x=1:12,y=c(3,5,1,6,2,9,7,10,11,4,12,8))
ggplot(z,aes(x=x,y=y))+geom_point(pch=3,size=5, stroke = 2)
```

[image]